# Prove that the Dyson series solves the differential equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I have a short question about Dyson series.

> Prove that $$U\left(t, 0\right) = \sum_{n}^{} \left(-i\right)^{n} \int_{0}^{t} dt_{1} \int_{0}^{t_{1}}dt_{2} ... \int_{0}^{t_{n - 1}} dt_{n} H_{I}\left(t_{1}\right)H_{I}\left(t_{2}\right)...H_{I}\left(t_{n}\right)$$ is a solution of $$ i\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\left(U\left(t, 0\right)\right) = H_{I}\left(t\right)U\left(t,0\right).$$

My attempt:

We can write: $$ U\left(t, 0\right) = \sum_{n}^{} (-i)^{n} \int_{0}^{t}dt_{1}f\left(t_{1}\right)$$ where $$f\left(t_{1}\right) = \int_{0}^{t_{1}}dt_{2} \int_{0}^{t_{2}}dt_{3} ... \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}dt_{n}H_{I}\left(t_{1}\right)H_{I}\left(t_{2}\right)...H_{I}\left(t_{n}\right).$$ Calculate the derivative ($\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\left(U\left(t, 0\right)\right)$):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}U\left(t,0\right) = \sum_{n}^{}(-i)^n\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left(\int_{0}^{t}dt_{1}f\left(t_{1}\right)\right) = \sum_{n}^{}\left(-i\right)^{n}f\left(t\right).$$

In other words:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}U\left(t,0\right) = \sum_{n}^{} \left(-i\right)^n \int_{0}^{t}dt_{2} \int_{0}^{t_{2}}dt_{3} ... \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}dt_{n}H_{I}\left(t\right)H_{I}\left(t_{2}\right)...H_{I}\left(t_{n}\right).$$

So:

$$ i\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}U\left(t,0\right) = \sum_{n}^{} \left(-i\right)^{n - 1} \int_{0}^{t}dt_{2} \int_{0}^{t_{2}}dt_{3} ... \int_{0}^{t_{n-1}}dt_{n}H_{I}\left(t\right)H_{I}\left(t_{2}\right)...H_{I}\left(t_{n}\right).$$

Now calculate $H_{I}\left(t\right)U\left(t, 0\right)$: $$H_{I}\left(t\right)U\left(t, 0\right)   =\sum_{n}^{} \left(-i\right)^{n} H_{I}\left(t\right) \int_{0}^{t} dt_{1} \int_{0}^{t_{1}}dt_{2} ... \int_{0}^{t_{n - 1}} dt_{n} H_{I}\left(t_{1}\right)H_{I}\left(t_{2}\right)...H_{I}\left(t_{n}\right).$$

How are these two terms equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How are these two terms equal?

I think you may have messed up a little bit with your evaluation of $f(t_1)$ at $t_1=t$. Or maybe it is just that your sum over $n$ in one of your equations (the one after taking the derivative) should start at $n=1$ since the derivative kills the $n=0$ term.

---

Anyways, it is helpful to just write out a few terms explicitly to see what is going on:
$$
U(t,0) = 1 + (-i)\int_0^t dt_1 H_I(t_1) + (-i)^2\int_0^t dt_1 H_I(t_1)\int_0^{t_1} dt_2 H_I(t_2) + \ldots
$$
So, we have:
$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = 0 -iH_I(t) +(-i)^2 H_I(t)\int_0^{t} dt_2 H_I(t_2) + \ldots\;,\tag{1}
$$
where, please note, the upper limit of the $dt_2$ integration is now $t$.

From Eq. (1), just pull out a factor of $-iH$ from each term:
$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = -iH_I(t)\left( 1 + (-i)\int_0^t dt_2 H_I(t_2) + \ldots \right)\;,
$$
but $t_2$ is a dummy variable, so just rename it $t_1$:
$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = -iH_I(t)\left( 1 + (-i)\int_0^t dt_1 H_I(t_1) + \ldots \right)
=-iH_I(t)U(t,0)
$$

Thus:
$$
i\frac{d}{dt}(U(t,0)) = H_I(t)U(t,0)
$$

Comment: Indeed. I wrote out the summation on both sides and it was not consistent. The term with the derivative, the sum should start with n = 1 instead of n = 0. Thank you for the answer! Another thing I want to add is that the sum is infinite. The terms on the leftside of the equation start with integrating over t2 then t3 and so on. We can relabel those to t1, t2 and so on (t2 -> t1, t3 -> t2 and so on).